# What is the equivalent of the SoundEffectInstance WP in WinRT,Win8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone, soundeffect

I was using SoundEffectInstance. It was provide me playing more than 1 sound at same moment. How can I do it in Windows 8 Metro Style, WinRT applications?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XAudio2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415762%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is your friend, you can also look at multiple answers that use this via SharpDX if you want to stay in C#. For an example see [How can I play multiple sounds at the same time using SharpDX in WinRT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642944/how-can-i-play-multiple-sounds-at-the-same-time-using-sharpdx-in-winrt)

Comment: I didn't understand it, could you explain it, please?